# Escape double quote in grep

Tags: linux, shell

I wanted to do grep for keywords with double quotes inside. To give a simple example:

```
echo "member":"time" | grep -e "member\""
```

That does not match. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't correctly escaping the input string, try:

```
echo "\"member\":\"time\"" | grep -e "member\""
```

Alternatively, you can use unescaped double quotes within single quotes:

```
echo '"member":"time"' | grep -e 'member"'
```

It's a matter of preference which you find clearer, although the second approach prevents you from nesting your command within another set of single quotes (e.g. `ssh 'cmd'`).

Comment: will this work ? `echo '"member":"time"' |grep -e "member"` didn't test

Comment: Almost. It needs to be `echo '"member":"time"' |grep -e 'member"'`. Both approaches are valid, but I prefer explicit escaping, as the intent is more clear.

Comment: yep, maybe edit your answer if you like someone might prefer this (+1)

Comment: This (using backslash) does not work on Windows for me. Actually it partially works, but I am unable to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: @RadimCernej I'd reccomend asking a windows specific question - it seems outside the scope of this one.