# How do I escape a double quote with GNU grep for windows/dos?

Tags: cmd, grep, gnu

I'm trying to search for

Assembly="Foobar

in all files and direct the output to tmp.txt

I've tried (cmd/error)

> grep -r "Assembly=\"Foobar" . >> tmp.txt 
>   error (invalid argument)
>
> grep -r "Assembly=""Foobar" . >> tmp.txt
>   error (not enough space)
>
> grep -r 'Assembly="Foobar' . >> tmp.txt
>   error (not enough space)

very frustrating.  Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [escape double quote in grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995353/escape-double-quote-in-grep)

Comment: no, I've seen/tried that

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to worry about escaping quotes for both grep and cmd.exe

grep expects quotes to be escaped as `\"`

cmd.exe escapes quotes as `^"`. The quote is a state machine, meaning unescaped quotes toggle quote semantics on and off. When quoting is on, special characters like `<`, `|`, `&`, etc are treated as literals. The first unescaped quote turns on quote semantics. The next quote turns quote semantics off. It is only possible to escape a quote when quoting is OFF. Unbalanced quotes result in the remainder being quoted. So in your case, the `>>tmp.txt` is not treated as redirection by cmd.exe, so it gets passed to grep as an argument.

Any of the following will work:

```
grep -r "Assembly=\"Foobar^" . >>tmp.txt
grep -r ^"Assembly=\"Foobar" . >>tmp.txt
grep -r ^"Assembly=\^"Foobar^" . >>tmp.txt
grep -r Assembly=\^"Foobar . >>tmp.txt
```

If your search term included spaces, then grep needs the enclosing quotes, so you would need any of the first three forms. The last form would not work with spaces in the search term.

Comment: This worked..  grep -r ^"Assembly=\"Foobar" . >> c:\temp\tmp.txt

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the quote is a state machine"

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit - I updated the answer in an attempt to improve the description of the state machine.

Comment: @dbenham, I don't get the first two first examples. In case 1) I see that as: `"Assembly=\"Foobar^"   ====>   (SEM_ON)Assembly=\(SEM_OFF)Foobar^"    ===>    Assembly=\Foobar"`   which doesn't seem to be what OP expects. Also, on example 2) `^"Assembly=\"Foobar"    ====>     ^"Assembly=\(SEM_ON)Foobar(SEM_OFF)    ====>    "Assembly=\Foobar`. I must be missing something. Could you please show me where am I wrong?

Comment: @Julio - cmd.exe does not remove quotes when it turns on or off quoting semantics - the quotes are passed on to grep. The only thing that is removed by cmd.exe is the `^` character (provided that quoting is off, so it functions as an escape)

Comment: Thanks a lot @dbenham! Now It is perfectly clear for me