# Sed with both " and ' in insert string

Tags: replace, sed, insert

I am using sed command in Ubuntu for making shell script.

I have a problem because the string I am inserting has both single and double quotes. Dashes also. This is the expample:

> sed -i "16i$('#myTable td:contains("Trunk do SW-BG-26,
>   GigabitEthernet0/22")').parents("tr").remove();" proba.txt

It should insert

```
$('#myTable td:contains("Trunk do SW-BG-26, GigabitEthernet0/22")').parents("tr").remove();
```

in line 16 of the file proba.txt

but instead it inserts

```
$('#myTable td:contains(
```

because it exits prematurely . How can resolve this, I cannot find solution here on site bcause I have both quotation signs and there are explanations only for one kind.

**2nd try**

I set \ in front every double quote except the outermost ones but I still didn't get what I want. Result is:

> .parents("tr").remove();

Then I put \ in front of every ' too but the result was an error in script. This is the 4th row:

> sed -i "16i$(\'#myTable td:contains(\"QinQ tunnel - SCnet wireless\")\').parents(\"tr\").remove();" proba.txt

This is the error:

> 4: skripta.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")

Maybe there is easier way to insert line into the file at the exact line if that line has ", ', /?

**3rd time is a charm**

Inserting many lines last day I came across another problem using sed. I want to insert this text:

> $(document).ready( function() {

with command:

> sed -i "16i$(document).ready( function() {" proba.txt

and I get as result this text inserted as document is something special or because of the $:

> .ready( function() {

Any thoughts about that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11995353 ... Escape your double quotes using backslashes.

Comment: Backslashe after or before double quote?
EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see that link. I'll give it a try.

Comment: The backslash goes before the quote.  You have to use it on every quote (except perhaps the outermost ones).

Comment: I set \ in front every double quote except the outermost ones but I still didn't get what I want. Result is: .parents("tr").remove();

Then I put \ in front of every ' too but the result was an error in script. This is the 4. row:
sed -i "16i$(\'#myTable td:contains(\"QinQ tunnel - SCnet wireless\")\').parents(\"tr\").remove();" proba.txt

This is the error:
4: skripta.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ")")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways around this.  The easy way out is to put the script into a file and use that on the command line.  For example, `sed.script` contains:

```
16i\
$('#myTable td:contains("Trunk do SW-BG-26, GigabitEthernet0/22")').parents("tr").remove();
```

and you run:

```
sed -f sed.script ...
```

If you want to do it without the file, then you have to decide whether to use single quotes or double quotes around your `sed -e` expression. Using single quotes is usually easier; there are no other special characters to worry about.  Each embedded single quote is replaced by `'\''`:

```
sed -e '16i\
$('\''#myTable td:contains("Trunk do SW-BG-26, GigabitEthernet0/22")'\'').parents("tr").remove();' ...
```

If you want to use double quotes, then each embedded double quote needs to be replaced by `\"`, but you also have to escape embedded back quotes `` ` ``, dollar signs `$` and backslashes `\`:

```
sed -e "16i\\
\$('#myTable td:contains(\"Trunk do SW-BG-26, GigabitEthernet0/22\")').parents(\"tr\").remove();" ...
```

(To the point: I forgot to escape the `$` before I checked the script with double quotes; I got the script with single quotes right first time.)

Because of all the extra checking, I almost invariably use single quotes, unless I need to get shell variables substituted into the script.

Comment: Thanks man, I will try with single quotes in the morning.
Just tell me if I use sed.script why it is different that writing it down in the console? I have 100 lines to insert similar to this one so I must make file, if it is much easier with sed script than I can do that way instead making bash script.

Comment: `sed` reads the file directly without the shell interpreting anything.  All the escaping is necessary to get the data past the shell.  What `sed` sees is identical to what's in the file; it is just a problem of persuading the shell to pass the data that's in the file to `sed` despite its normally helpful rules for expanding variables and removing quotes and so on and so forth.

Comment: I wrote another issue about this in main window, please take a look if you can.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to read my answer -- you need to put escapes (backslashes) in front of the `$` signs.  As it is, you have a program `document` which exits quietly when given no command arguments.  The `$(document)` captures the output from the `document` command and includes that text in the `sed` script.  This is why I use single quotes!

Comment: I am sorry to force you, but I am not able to try this till morning (in 8 hours) and I am trying to get as many help as I can so I can get to wok in the morning. You are real pall and a heart, and I am just a beginner in this.

Comment: I used sed.script as you proposed and it works perfectly!
You're a star mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "6 i\\
\$('#myTable td:contains(\"Trunk do SW-BG-26, GigabitEthernet0/22\")').parents(\"tr\").remove();" proba.txt
```

escape the double quote, the slash and new line needed after the `i` instruction and the `$` due to double quote shell interpretation