# Passing quoted variables in remote ssh command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I want to grep through a few files for a string. In this example I want to grep for "test 1234"

```
#!/bin/bash

variable="test 1234"
ssh root@server "grep "$variable" /path/*"
```

This script doesn't work because test 1234 is passed to the server instead of "test 1234"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes around `$variable` in your command:

```
ssh root@server "grep \"$variable\" /path/*"
```

As it stands, the variable is expanding but because the quotes aren't escaped, the command is searching for the text `test` in the files `1234` *and* `/path/*`

Comment: or alternatively: `ssh root@server "grep '$variable' /path/*"`  : the local-script level `"` ensure that `$variable` is replaced by its local-script value, and the remote grep then receives that value within a single quote.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to escape the double quotes with a `\` backslash character.

see [escape double quote in grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995353/escape-double-quote-in-grep)