# How to match double quotes using grep

Tags: regex, grep, double-quotes

I thought I knew this(or at least how to google for it)!

But I can't figure out how to match double quotes using grep when searching for patterns in text file. I tried to escape the double quotes symbol with a backslash, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
>cat trial.txt  
"Bill" is here and "Ben" is there

> grep -iE "and \"ben\" is" trial.txt
Unmatched ".
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: It works on my machine

Comment: Fun fact, your code works for me with mingw bash 4.3.42 and grep 2.2. What version do you use?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995353/escape-double-quote-in-grep

Comment: @TamasRev

grep is 2.7

and I am using tcsh version 6.15

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use single quotes to consider literal meaning of every  character.

```
grep 'and "Ben" is' trial.txt
```

Comment: I was this close to trying it with single quotes - but decided instead to bother you nice folks over here at stackoverflow with my first question. 
It works perfectly with single quotes. Thanks!